# Displaying an image in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am fetching data from a database using a servlet and displaying in a JSP. I am getting the String, but not getting an image.

I am getting output like this: `English [B@12fd16f`

Here is my servlet class:

```
@WebServlet("/ReadFindServlet")
 public class ReadFindServlet extends HttpServlet {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private List<Find> findList = new ArrayList<>();    

public List<Find> getFindList() {
    return findList;
}

public void setFindList(List<Find> findList) {
    this.findList = findList;
}   

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ResultSet resultSet = null;

    try {

    resultSet = LoginDao.readFind();

    while(resultSet.next()){
        Find find = new Find();

        find.setSubject(resultSet.getString(1));                
        find.setImage(resultSet.getBytes(2));

        response.setContentType("image/jpeg");              


        findList.add(find);

    }
    setFindList(findList);          

    request.setAttribute("findList", findList);
    RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("jsp/find.jsp");
    requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

**Find.java**

```
public class Find {

private String subject;
private byte[] image;

public String getSubject() {
    return subject;
}
public void setSubject(String subject) {
    this.subject = subject;
}
public byte[] getImage() {
    return image;
}
public void setImage(byte[] image) {
    this.image = image;
}

}
```

**jsp** -

```
<c:forEach items="${findList}" var="findRecord">
     <h1>Here are details - </h1>                 
     ${findRecord.subject}                 
     <img src="/ReadFindServlet"${findRecord.image }/>
</c:forEach>
```

I have tried this also -

```
    <img src="/ReadFindServlet/${findRecord.image }"/>
    <img src="{findRecord.image }"/>
```

But didn't work.

**please help.**

Comment: You can't insert binary data in the `src` attribute of the `<img>` tag. The `src` attribute specifies a URL, which the browser will use to retrieve the binary data *separately*.

Comment: create a servlet which streams back a byte array of the image.  This can be then be called using `<img src="imageServlet?file=filename"/>`.  Of course this url can also be tested just as a normal url in a browser

Comment: @Andreas. Thanks for reply. How to do this. please suggest & also how should i store image & retrieve. I am storing as largeblob.

Comment: @ScaryWombat please suggest how to "create a servlet which streams back a byte array of the image" . thanks

Comment: @jaythakur as you dont seem to be able to use Google, here you http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2007/04/imageservlet.html

Comment: or https://thelogicalwebmaster.wordpress.com/2011/03/02/stream-and-serve-with-java-servlets/

Comment: @ScaryWombat. thank you so much.

Comment: @ScaryWombat. thanks. Now i am getting string & image both. I made another servlet for image calling. But another problem i am facing here that when i am refreshing the jsp page, I am getting same data again again i:e; duplicate data. how to solve this ? please suggest.